# No valid certificate for website under test produbile? (using HTMLUnit / Java)

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, x509certificate

I'm trying to create a valid certificate for automating access to a website. I'm using HTMLUnit in Java.

This is my code:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableEntryException {

        driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);


        host = "192.x.x.x";
        String name = "username", password = "password";
        webClient.addRequestHeader(name, password);
        URL url = new URL("https://"+"host"+"/<rest of url>");

        try {
            webClient.openWindow(url, "Main");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

There have been problems with the certificate of a site

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:396)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:194)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1372)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1291)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:390)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.openWindow(WebClient.java:877)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.openWindow(WebClient.java:854)
>     at
>   testExamples.SeleniumHTMLUnitHeadlessTest.init(SeleniumHTMLUnitHeadlessTest.java:274)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)

Well,I downloaded the certificate and imported it into cacerts file in JAVA_Home.

The result was an exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for
>   <192.x.x.x> doesn't match common name of the certificate subject:
>       at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.matchCN(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.verify(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier.verify(DefaultHostnameVerifier.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:397)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:355)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:194)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1372)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1291)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:390)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.openWindow(WebClient.java:877)
>     at
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.openWindow(WebClient.java:854)
>     at
>   testExamples.SeleniumHTMLUnitHeadlessTest.init(SeleniumHTMLUnitHeadlessTest.java:274)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:166)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)

ok, I searched and the reason seemed to be an invalid CN.

I built a new certificate using the same csr contents except the CN (I used the hostname (the ip in the code) for this), imported it into cacerts file in JAVA_Home and then I got exactly the same exception as using the first certificate.
But I can't imagine that there is no solution. Could you please help me out of this?

Please let me know if you need further information.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching off certification check. If you have the same problem, look at this: http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/